# Windows Phone 7 automatic call contact

Tags: windows-phone-7, phone-call, silverlight-toolkit

I've been trying to make a program which will call a hard coded contact in WP7. Im using this code for the call function

```
    PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
                                    phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "123456789";
                                    phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "person 1";
                                    phoneCallTask.Show();
```

and there is this pop up menu like [this](http://developers.de/cfsfilesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/damir_5F00_dobric/image_5F00_2C2B6F51.png/)!(this one is from google images)

I would want to know if there is a way in which I can call that contact without manually pressing the call button or pressing any key.

Comment: No, there isn't. User has to start the call himself clicking the popup `Call` button.

Comment: is there a code that can instance a "tap" event in the area where the call button is?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to do it and there is no way to automate the tap on the **Call** button. This feature is by-design and is there for security purposes, to protect the user from rogue applications that might trigger expensive calls (e.g. international or to paid services).